Collect with inline function
f(x) = x+2  
p(y) = if(y>2) true else false

List(4,7,1,3,9).collect{ case I
if p(f(i)) => f(i)}

This works - but if f(x) was a heavy compute function, it would mean I am forced to call it twice.
If I take output of f(x) into a val, and feed into p(x) above - code wouldn't compile.
How do I avoid the repeat call - without needing any additional iteration of the list

In this case using separate map and filter calls is better than collect:
List(4,7,1,3,9).map(f).filter(p)

A view can be used to avoid multiple iterations of the List if that is an issue.
List(4,7,1,3,9).view.map(f).filter(p).toList

If the result is going to be used in a further iteration then the toList might not be necessary.

Wouldn't this result in an additional iteration of the sequence

Yes, but if f is a heavy compute function then it won't be a significant overhead. Using a view would avoid that if necessary, I've updated the answer to show how.

You could combine f and p into a custom extractor object (into its unapply method):
def f(x: Int): String = x.toString
def p(y: String): Boolean = y.length <= 1

object FP:
  def unapply(x: Int): Option[String] =
    Some(f(x)).filter(p)

def collectStuff(l: List[Int]): List[String] =
  l.collect{ case FP(y) => y }


See this page of the official Scala documentation for more details on extractor objects.

def f(x: Int) = {
  println (s"f($x)")
  x+2
}
def p (y: Int) = y > 2

LazyList(4,7,1,3,9).map(i => f(i)).filter(y => p(y)).toList

